# Python - How can I do a string find on a Unicode character that is a variable?

Tags: python, unicode

This works

```
s = 'jiā'
s.find(u'\u0101')
```

How do I do something like this:

```
s = 'jiā'
zzz = '\u0101'
s.find(zzz)
```

Since I'm using a variable now, how do I indicate the string represented by the variable is Unicode?

Comment: note: `len(u'\u0101') == 1` (one unicode codepoint). `len('\u0101') == 6` (six bytes in Python 2) and `len(b'\u0101'.decode('unicode-escape')) == 1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Since I'm using a variable now, how do I indicate the string represented by the variable is Unicode?

By defining it as a Unicode string in the first place.

```
zzz = u"foo"
```

Or, if you already have a string in some other encoding, by converting it to Unicode (the original encoding must be specified if the string is non-ASCII).

```
zzz = unicode(zzz, encoding="latin1")
```

Or by using Python 3 where all strings are Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

`zzz` as defined in your post is a plain `str` object, not a `unicode` object, so there is no way to indicate that it is something it actually isn't.  You can convert the `str` object to a `unicode` object, though, by specifying an encoding:

```
s.find(zzz.decode("utf-8"))
```

Substitue `utf-8` by whatever encoding the string is encoded in.

Note that in your example

```
zzz = '\u0101'
```

`zzz` is a plain string of length 6.  There is no easy way to fix this wrong string literal afterwards, except for hacks along the lines of

```
ast.literal_eval("u'" + zzz + "'")
```

Comment: There's a less hackish way to rescue that string: `"\u0101".decode("unicode-escape")`

Comment: @ThomasK: Thanks, I obviously wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (I ignore when) you will have to decode also the string that you are looking in:

```
s.decode("utf-8").find(u"\u0101")
```